# Is it possible to specify offset and limit via hibernate criterion?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following method:

```
public Junction build(Junction prototype, Integer offset, Integer limit) {
    //Setting offset and limit
    return prototype;
}
```

We can do that via `Criteria.setFrstResult(int offset)` and `Criteria.sendMaxResult(int limit)`. Is it possible to set that restriction via criterion ever? Because `Juntion.add(Criterion criterion)` only exists.